# ROS2 creating a subscriber in a class

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 ; ROS2 Eloquent
I am trying to run this code by defining callback in the class.

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/image.hpp"

using namespace std::placeholders;

class MinimalDepthSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node {
  public:
    MinimalDepthSubscriber()
        : Node("zed_depth_tutorial") {

        rmw_qos_profile_t camera_qos_profile = rmw_qos_profile_sensor_data;
        mSub = create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>(
                   "/zed/zed_node/depth/depth_registered",
                   std::bind(&MinimalDepthSubscriber::depthCallback, this, _1),
                   camera_qos_profile);
    }

 protected:
    void depthCallback(const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::SharedPtr msg) {
        // Get a pointer to the depth values casting the data
        // pointer to floating point
        float* depths = (float*)(&msg->data[0]);

        // Image coordinates of the center pixel
        int u = msg->width / 2;
        int v = msg->height / 2;

        // Linear index of the center pixel
        int centerIdx = u + msg->width * v;

        // Output the measure
        RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Center distance : %g m", depths[centerIdx]);
    }

 private:
    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::SharedPtr mSub;
};


// The main function
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    auto depth_node = std::make_shared<MinimalDepthSubscriber>();

    rclcpp::spin(depth_node);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is this -

```
colcon build --packages-select stereo_ground_surface
Starting >>> stereo_ground_surface
--- stderr: stereo_ground_surface                             
/home/hsharma/Documents/internship/ws/ros2_ws/src/stereo_ground_surface/simulation_ws/src/stereo_detection/src/multisense_subscriber.cpp: In constructor ‘MinimalDepthSubscriber::MinimalDepthSubscriber()’:
/home/hsharma/Documents/internship/ws/ros2_ws/src/stereo_ground_surface/simulation_ws/src/stereo_detection/src/multisense_subscriber.cpp:87:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘MinimalDepthSubscriber::create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>(const char [37], std::_Bind_helper<false, void (MinimalDepthSubscriber::*)(std::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::msg::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >), MinimalDepthSubscriber*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type, rmw_qos_profile_t&)’
                    camera_qos_profile);
```

What is happening here? Is my function definition wrong? Are there changes to the `rclcpp::Node::create_subscription` function

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359479/ros2-creating-a-subscriber-in-a-class/) by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2020-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your arguments to `create_subscription` are around the wrong way. It should be:

```
mSub = create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>(
           "/zed/zed_node/depth/depth_registered",
           camera_qos_profile,
           std::bind(&MinimalDepthSubscriber::depthCallback, this, _1));
```

Your QOS is also the wrong object type. You have to pass it a `rclcpp::QoS` reference.

See [this example](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/eloquent/demo_nodes_cpp/src/topics/listener_best_effort.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2020-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2020-08-15**:
thanks. yeah you are right. my bad